# Laravel Worker does not working in docker

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, queue, worker

I need add a worker in Docker.  I use Laravel 5.7 and docker-compose version 3.

docker-compose file is:

```
potatoes:
build:
  context: ./potatoes
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  args:
    environment: local
ports:
  - '5000:80'
links:
  - redis
  - potatoesdb
  - elasticsearch
volumes:
  - ./potatoes:/var/www/html/app
```

Dockerfile is:

```
FROM my-company-laravel:latest

#Copiamos las configuraciones de nginx, el host y supervisor
ADD docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD docker/virtualhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

ARG environment

RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip

#Copiamos el projecto con los modulos de node y los assets compilados
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./ /var/www/html/app
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./.env.${environment:-local} /var/www/html/app/.env

#Aplicamos los permisos que corresponden
RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/app/storage
RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/app/bootstrap

#Copiamos composer
COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

##Download composer packages
WORKDIR /var/www/html/app
RUN composer install
RUN chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/app/vendor
RUN php artisan key:generate

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Inside Laravel project I created a docker folder with:

supervisord file:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon = true
logfile = /tmp/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 0

[program:php-fpm]
command=/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm --nodaemonize --fpm-config /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=false

[program:nginx]
command =/usr/sbin/nginx -g "daemon off;"
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes = 0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes = 0

[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php artisan queue:work redis --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=3
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/tmp/worker.log
```

And there are another two files, but are irrelevants I thing. (nginx.conf and virtualhot.conf)

The application runs ok, but the worker doesn`t working  and I have to run php artisan queue:work...

[image]

This image show the file /tmp/supervisord.log:

Comment: Does the ```/tmp/worker.log``` file have any message related to this?

Comment: Consider adding a separate container with an entrypoint executing `php artisan queue:work` instead of trying to add this to your web application container.

Comment: I didn`t see @sebasaenz, I`m going to check.

Comment: @brice what is the difference? My tech lead told my to put worker into the container

Comment: @brice both ways are correct, there's nothing wrong with running ```supervisor``` in the container.

Comment: @JuanPabloB let me know if you found something

Comment: @sebasaenz  The problem was in the docker compose, you had to change the link to depends_on, in this way, initialize redis first